# html-loader only works on index.html file

Tags: html, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

I'm working on a static site project, and have to now add multiple pages using the same header and footer. I'm trying to do this by turning the `header.html` and `footer.html` files into partials.

I've setup my `webpack.config.js` to use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` where the template is the `index.html` file.

```
plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),
    ]
```

I've also called the partials in the `index.html` file as follows:

```
<body>
    <%= require('html-loader!./partials/header.html').default %>
    
    
    <%= require('html-loader!./partials/home.html').default %>


    <%= require('html-loader!./partials/footer.html').default %>
</body>
```

This works on the index file. But now I've got to add a `portfolio.html` page and reuse the header and footer.
When I call the partials the same way, they render as strings on the html page

[image]

Could someone help me with this? I don't know how to reuse the partials in other html pages.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I did find a solution to this. @MahbubAlamKhan. I switched out from webpack and used gulp, with a mixture of nunjucks as a templating language. Wasn't ideal, but it got the job done

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with `html-loader`. You didn't use `html-webpack-plugin` to process the `portfolio.html` file. This plugin will use ejs/lodash template by default to process the special template tag `<%= >`.

See [Generating Multiple HTML Files](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#generating-multiple-html-files):

> To generate more than one HTML file, declare the plugin **more than once** in your plugins array

E.g.

Project structure(after building):

```
$ tree -L 3 -I node_modules
.
├── dist
│   ├── home.js
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── portfolio.html
│   └── portfolio.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── partials
│   │   ├── footer.html
│   │   ├── header.html
│   │   └── home.html
│   ├── portfolio.html
│   └── portfolio.js
└── webpack.config.js

3 directories, 14 files
```

`src/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="IE=edge"
        />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%= require('html-loader!./partials/header.html').default %>
    <%= require('html-loader!./partials/home.html').default %>
    <%= require('html-loader!./partials/footer.html').default %>
  </body>
</html>
```

`src/portfolio.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%= require('html-loader!./partials/header.html').default %>
    <main>This is portfolio page</main>
    <%= require('html-loader!./partials/footer.html').default %>
  </body>
</html>
```

`src/partials/header.html`:

```html
<header>This is header</header>
```

`src/partials/footer.html`:

```html
<footer>This is footer</footer>
```

`src/partials/home.html`:

```html
<main>This is home page</main>
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        home: './src/index.js',
        portfolio: './src/portfolio.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'src/index.html',
            chunks: ['home'],
            minify: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'portfolio.html',
            template: 'src/portfolio.html',
            chunks: ['portfolio'],
            minify: false,
        }),
    ],
};
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

assets by path *.html 791 bytes
  asset index.html 422 bytes [compared for emit]
  asset portfolio.html 369 bytes [compared for emit]
assets by path *.js 0 bytes
  asset home.js 0 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: home)
  asset portfolio.js 0 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: portfolio)
./src/index.js 1 bytes [built] [code generated]
./src/portfolio.js 1 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 277 ms
```

**Output**

`dist/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="IE=edge"
        />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>index</title>
    <script defer src="home.js"></script></head>
    <body>
    <header>This is header</header> 
    <main>This is home page</main> 
    <footer>This is footer</footer> 
  </body>
</html>
```

`dist/portfolio.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>portfolio</title>
    <script defer src="portfolio.js"></script></head>
    <body>
    <header>This is header</header> 
    <main>This is portfolio page</main>
    <footer>This is footer</footer> 
  </body>
</html>
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
        "webpack": "^5.80.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```